# Derivative and Green function of Fractional Laplacian in a bounded domain: $(-\Delta)^s\nabla_x G(\bar x,z) = 0 \text{ in } \Omega $?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Let $G$ be the Green function of the Fractional Laplacian $(-\Delta)^s$ in a domain $\Omega$ (which is known explicitly for the special case of the ball: [link](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Fractional_Laplacian#Green.27s_function_for_the_ball)). Let $\bar x \in \Omega$ be fixed. Does  $\nabla_x G(\bar x,z)$ satisfy
$$(-\Delta)^s\nabla_x G(\bar x,z) = 0 \text{ in } \Omega \ ?$$
In other words I'm asking if $\nabla_x$ and $(-\Delta)^s$ commute *on a bounded domain $\Omega$*, which was answered in $\mathbb R^n$ in [Derivative of fractional Laplacian is the fractional Laplacian of the derivative](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294933/derivative-of-fractional-laplacian-is-the-fractional-laplacian-of-the-derivative)